# how to replace all Uppercase letters with spacing?

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = "MaryGoesToSchool";

$expectedoutput = "Mary Goes To School";
```

Comment: How do you expect the output for "MaryHasACat"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
$string = "MaryGoesToSchool";

$spaced = preg_replace('/([A-Z])/', ' $1', $string);
var_dump($spaced);
```

This :

- Matches the uppercase letters
- And replace each one of them by a space, and what was matched

Which gives this output :

```
string ' Mary Goes To School' (length=20)
```

And you can then use :

```
$trimmed = trim($spaced);
var_dump($trimmed);
```

To remove the space at the beginning, which gets you :

```
string 'Mary Goes To School' (length=19)
```

Comment: Then `preg_replace('/ *([A-Z])/', ' $1', $string);`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$expectedoutput = preg_replace('/(\p{Ll})(\p{Lu})/u', '\1 \2', $string);
```

The `\p{…}` notations are describing characters via [Unicode character properties](http://docs.php.net/manual/regexp.reference.unicode.php); `\p{Ll}` denotes a lowercase letter and `\p{Lu}` an uppercase letter.

Another approach would be this:

```
$expectedoutput = preg_replace('/\p{Lu}(?<=\p{L}\p{Lu})/u', ' \0', $string);
```

Here every uppercase letter is only prepended with a space if it’s preceded by another letter. So `MaryHasACat` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-regex solution which i use to format a camelCase string to a more readable format:

```
<?php
function formatCamelCase( $string ) {
        $output = "";
        foreach( str_split( $string ) as $char ) {
                strtoupper( $char ) == $char and $output and $output .= " ";
                $output .= $char;
        }
        return $output;
}

echo formatCamelCase("MaryGoesToSchool"); // Mary Goes To School
echo formatCamelCase("MaryHasACat"); // Mary Has A Cat
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$string = 'MaryGoesToSchool';
$nStr = preg_replace_callback('/[A-Z]/', function($matches){
    return $matches[0] = ' ' . ucfirst($matches[0]);
}, $string);
echo trim($nStr);
```